# 2 animations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make multiple animations on the same page. but I don't know how to create another variable. Here is the sample, [from Codepen](http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/CHwDx?editors=011).

I tried creating another `"imageFile = new Image()"` naming it `"imageFile2 = new Image()` but it didn't seem to work.

I am very new in this. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
var appHeight = 400,
    appWidth = 1000,
    appCenterX = appWidth/2,
    appCenterY = appHeight/2,
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
       container: 'container',
       width: appWidth,
       height:appHeight
     }),
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer(),
    imageFile = new Image(),
    creature,
    bezTween;

imageFile.src = "http://www.greensock.com/_img/codepen/bezierCreature/creature_red.png";

var creatureGroup = new Kinetic.Group();
creature = new Kinetic.Image({
  image: imageFile,
  width:27,
  height:29,
  x:-16,
  y:-16
});

bezTween = new TweenMax(creatureGroup, 6, {
  bezier:{
    type:"soft", 
    values:[{setX:100, setY:250}, {setX:300, setY:0}, {setX:500, setY:400}, {setX:appWidth+20, setY:20}],
    //autoRotate needs to know how to adjust x/y/rotation so we pass in the names of the apporpriate KineticJS methods
    autoRotate:["setX", "setY", "setRotationDeg"]
  }, 
  ease:Linear.easeNone, autoCSS:false, repeat:10});

  for (i = 0; i<200; i++){
  bezTween.progress(i/200);
  var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
  radius:2,
    fill:'#333',
    x:bezTween.target.getX(),
    y:bezTween.target.getY()
});
layer.add(circle);
  layer.draw();
bezTween.restart();  
}

var creatureLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
creatureGroup.add(creature); 
creatureLayer.add(creatureGroup);
stage.add(layer);
stage.add(creatureLayer);

TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener("tick", redraw);

function redraw(){
  creatureLayer.draw();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create second `creature2`.

```
var appHeight = 400,
    appWidth = 1000,
    appCenterX = appWidth/2,
    appCenterY = appHeight/2,
    stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
       container: 'container',
       width: appWidth,
       height:appHeight
     }),
    layer = new Kinetic.Layer(),
    imageFile = new Image(),
    imageFile2 = new Image(),
    creature,
    creature2,
    bezTween;

imageFile.src = "http://www.greensock.com/_img/codepen/bezierCreature/creature_red.png";

imageFile2.src = "http://www.greensock.com/_img/codepen/bezierCreature/creature_red.png";

var creatureGroup = new Kinetic.Group();
creature2 = new Kinetic.Image({
  image: imageFile2,
  width:50,
  height:50,
  x:20,
  y:-16
});
```

Check Your [Updated Codepen Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVLZBB).

**Edit:**

Here i updated codepen with different path for another creature as you required.

I created another path there.

```
bezTween1 = new TweenMax(creatureGroup1, 6, {
  bezier:{
    type:"soft", 
    values:[{setX:150, setY:300}, {setX:350, setY:0}, {setX:550, setY:450}, {setX:appWidth+50, setY:50}],
    //autoRotate needs to know how to adjust x/y/rotation so we pass in the names of the apporpriate KineticJS methods
    autoRotate:["setX", "setY", "setRotationDeg"]
  }, 
  ease:Linear.easeNone, autoCSS:false, repeat:10});
```

Check [Codepen Here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVLZBB)

Comment: Thank you for your respond but I guess I didn't make it clear because that is not exactly what I want. 

What I want is to create another animation with different path as well. Because as what I can see from your respond is you created another 'Creature' but using the same existing path. 

I am trying to make another 'Creature' with new path (could be different random direction). Thank you and sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: @Farah WC. Glad to help. You should accept it as a answer if it solved your issue. by check on correct symbol.